# Having an issue setting framework id

Tags: linux, configuration, playframework

I'm about to deploy my first Play app, (very excited). I read on playframework.org about the framework id and I want to rejigger my config to take advantage of it. I'm currently on dev but I want to deploy to stage. I want to edit my config to differentiate between dev and stage settings.

My problem, when I type play id I get the following error, "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/play-1.2.3/id'"

I'm new to Linux BTW.

So I thought, hmmm, maybe I need to sudo? So I use "sudo su -" and try again, but now I get the error, "command not found".

Comment: The issue was that play-1.2.3 was not in my path for my sudo account. Once sudo(ed) in, I ran export PATH=$PATH:/opt/play-1.2.3 and then I was able to run the play id command.

I AM SO SMART SMRT, learning Linux all on my own baby!

Comment: You should post your answer as such (not as a comment) and accept it so people can easily see what the solution was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that play-1.2.3 was not in my path for my sudo account. Once sudo(ed) in, I ran export PATH=$PATH:/opt/play-1.2.3 and then I was able to run the play id command. I AM SO SMART SMRT, learning Linux all on my own baby!